# How to write a console log from a frame using Selenium?

Tags: java, selenium, selenium-chromedriver

I get a log using Selenium set pref
 `logPrefs.enable(LogType.BROWSER, Level.ALL);` 
and put it this way `LogEntries logEntries = driver.manage().logs().get(LogType.BROWSER);
            for (LogEntry entry : logEntries) {
                System.out.println(entry.getMessage());` in the output stream, I am not getting the entire console log. Log which gives the frame, do not display selenium. **How to get a log from the frame?** 
Switching to this frame does not produce results. `driver.switchTo().frame(driver.findElement(By.cssSelector("link")));`

Answer (score 0):

I had a problem where I was not able to interact with elements inside a frame. Instead of finding the element, just type:

driver.SwitchTo().frame("element id");

and then

driver.SwitchTo().DefaultContent();

Comment: My problem is not in the elements, but in the browser console logging. Logs are not output from the frame! What to do?

Comment: @ARTSIOMVORONETSKI any solution?

Comment: @Fillipe solution was lost in 2018